# Beamer + glossaries: how to make \printglossaries show the location in frames rather than PDF pages

Tags: beamer, glossaries

I'm trying to use the `glossaries` package with beamer. In `\printglossaries`, the entries are shown with page number. The problem I have is that page number is pages in PDF: I'd like to see  which slide (frame) of the presentation the entry is on.

I think it's easier to see, so please bear with me for a while.

example.tex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{example}{
  name={example},
  description={Examples are good}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Prepare} % First frame with two PDF pages
  This \textit<2>{will} make a difference.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Use glossary} % Second frame
  Hi, \gls{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Glossary}
  \printglossaries
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`$ pdflatex example.tex && makeglossaries example && pdflatex example.tex`

See the glossary frame:

[image]

This is the 3rd frame (/3 frames total) of the presentation, and is the 4th page of the PDF. The term `example` is used in the 3rd page of the PDF as shown in the `\printglossaries`, but is on the 2nd frame, the number of which I prefer to use.

How can I use the frame numbering, rather than page numbering?

Comment: Welcome ! By default, the counter used by `glossaries` should be the page number. So it seems there is a discrepancy there. I believe only Nicola Talbot could answer that unfortunately. I looked a bit to the `glossaries` documentation, but nothing came out so far.